# Editing the html content of <description> of a KML using lxml

Tags: python, html, lxml, kml, google-earth

I want to replace the html inside the description tag of a KML with a new, formatted html.

My kml has this structure:

```
<html>
 <body>
  <kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2" xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
   <document id="WATER_MAINLINE_trim" xsi:schemalocation="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2 http://schemas.opengis.net/kml/2.2.0/ogckml22.xsd http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2 http://code.google.com/apis/kml/schema/kml22gx.xsd">
    <name>
     WATER_MAINLINE_trim
    </name>
    <open>
     1
    </open>
    <snippet maxlines="0">
    </snippet>
    <style id="LineStyle00">
     <LabelStyle>
            <color>00000000</color>
            <scale>0</scale>
        </LabelStyle>
        <LineStyle>
            <color>ff240087</color>
        </LineStyle>
        <PolyStyle>
            <color>00000000</color>
            <outline>0</outline>
        </PolyStyle>
    </style>
    <folder id="FeatureLayer0">
     <name>
      WATER_MAINLINE_trim
     </name>
     <open>
      1
     </open>
     <snippet maxlines="0">
     </snippet>
     <placemark id="ID_00000">
      <name>
       0100026491
      </name>
      <snippet maxlines="0">
      </snippet>
      <description>
       <meta content="text/html" http-equiv="Content-Type" />
       <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="content-type" />
       <table style="font-family:Arial,Verdana,Times;font-size:12px;text-align:left;width:100%;border-collapse:collapse;padding:3px 3px 3px 3px">
        <tr style="text-align:center;font-weight:bold;background:#9CBCE2">
         <td>
          0100026491
         </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
         <td>
          <table style="font-family:Arial,Verdana,Times;font-size:12px;text-align:left;width:100%;border-spacing:0px; padding:3px 3px 3px 3px">
           <tr>
            <td>
             FID
            </td>
            <td>
             0
            </td>
           </tr>
           <tr bgcolor="#D4E4F3">
            <td>
             PRIKEY
            </td>
            <td>
             0100026491
            </td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
            <td>
             YEAR_INST
            </td>
            <td>
             2001
            </td>
           </tr>
           <tr bgcolor="#D4E4F3">
            <td>
             PIPE_CLASS
            </td>
            <td>
             PRIMARY
            </td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
            <td>
             DIAMETER
            </td>
            <td>
             1500
            </td>
           </tr>
           <tr bgcolor="#D4E4F3">
            <td>
             MATERIAL
            </td>
            <td>
             SP
            </td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
            <td>
             STATUS
            </td>
            <td>
             ACTIVE
            </td>
           </tr>
           <tr bgcolor="#D4E4F3">
            <td>
             BA
            </td>
            <td>
             FCOM
            </td>
           </tr>
           <tr>
            <td>
             SUBCLASS
            </td>
            <td>
             WATER MAINLINE
            </td>
           </tr>
          </table>
         </td>
        </tr>
       </table>
      </description>
     </placemark>
    </folder>
   </document>
  </kml>
 </body>
</html>
```

And I have this new html:

```
newhtml="""<![CDATA[ \n<!------------TITLE SUBCLASS---------------->\n  <tr>\n    <td colspan="2" align="center">\n      <b><font color=\'#090259\' size=\'6\' style = \'bold\'>LA MESA BALARA</font><b>\n    </td>/n  </tr>\n<!------------IMAGE---------------->\n  <tr>\n    <td colspan="2" align="center">\n      <img src= http://static.rappler.com/images/640-lamesadam-20120728.jpg, width=500, height = 223, alt="picture" />\n    </td>\n  </tr>\n<!------------PRIKEY---------------->\n  <tr>\n    <td bgcolor = \'#090259\', align="center" >\n      <p><font color = \'FFFFFF\', size =\'4\'>PRIKEY</p>\n    </td>\n \n    <td bgcolor = \'#d8d8ff\' align="center">\n      <p>0100026491</p>\n    </td>\n<!------------YEAR INSTALLED---------------->\n  <tr>\n    <td bgcolor = \'#090259\', align="center" >\n      <p><font color = \'FFFFFF\', size =\'4\'>Year Installed</p>\n    </td>\n \n    <td bgcolor = \'#d8d8ff\' align="center">\n      <p>2001</p>\n    </td>\n<!------------PIPE CLASS---------------->\n  <tr>\n    <td bgcolor = \'#090259\', align="center" >\n      <p><font color = \'FFFFFF\', size =\'4\'>Pipe Class</p>\n    </td>\n \n    <td bgcolor = \'#d8d8ff\' align="center">\n      <p>PRIMARY</p>\n    </td>\n<!------------DIAMETER---------------->\n  <tr>\n    <td bgcolor = \'#090259\', align="center" >\n      <p><font color = \'FFFFFF\', size =\'4\'>Diameter (mm)</p>\n    </td>\n \n    <td bgcolor = \'#d8d8ff\' align="center">\n      <p>1500.000000</p>\n    </td>\n<!------------MATERIAL---------------->\n  <tr>\n    <td bgcolor = \'#090259\', align="center" >\n      <p><font color = \'FFFFFF\', size =\'4\'>Material</p>\n    </td>\n \n    <td bgcolor = \'#d8d8ff\' align="center">\n      <p>SP</p>\n    </td>\n<!------------STATUS---------------->\n  <tr>\n    <td bgcolor = \'#090259\', align="center" >\n      <p><font color = \'FFFFFF\', size =\'4\'>Status</p>\n    </td>\n \n    <td bgcolor = \'#d8d8ff\' align="center">\n      <p>ACTIVE</p>\n    </td>\n<!------------BUSINESS ADDRESS---------------->\n  <tr>\n    <td bgcolor = \'#090259\', align="center" >\n      <p><font color = \'FFFFFF\', size =\'4\'>Business Address</p>\n    </td>\n \n    <td bgcolor = \'#d8d8ff\' align="center">\n      <p>Fairview-Commonwealth</p>\n    </td>]]>"""
```

How do I properly replace it inside a parsed kml using *lxml*, and still be a valid KML? With 'valid', I pertain to kml that can be loaded on Google Earth.  I have tried doing the replacement using BeautifulSoup but my outfile gets an error when loaded on Google Earth. It says, *"Unexpected element "html""*. So I just want to use lxml for this instead. Any help will be appreciated. Thank you!

I have this sample kml which contain 5 LineString placemarks.

trim.kml = https://sites.google.com/site/kmlhostingmwss/trim.kml

Comment: Please check the namespaces of KML document. The `xsi` prefix is not declared in `<kml>` root (rendering it not well-formed). I assume a copy error for: `<kml xmlns:xsi="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2"...>`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out @Parfait. Btw, if you are familiar with GIS, I got my kml by using 'Layer to KML' on ArcGIS. It is basically ArcGIS who gives such kml structure with that namespaces. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since KML is a valid XML file, consider [XSLT](https://www.w3.org/Style/XSL/), the transformation language used specifically to modify XML documents and Python's lxml can run XSLT 1.0 scripts.

Specifically, below the dynamic XSLT is parsed from string, running first the Identity Transform to copy document as is and then replaces every occurrence of `<description>` with the newhtml variable.

```
import lxml.etree as ET

# READ IN KML FILE
dom = ET.parse('trim.kml')

newhtml = """<![CDATA[\n<!------------TITLE SUBCLASS---------------->\n  <tr>\n    <td colspan="2" align="center">\n      <b><font color=\'#090259\' size=\'6\' style = \'bold\'>LA MESA BALARA</font><b>\n    </td>/n  </tr>\n<!------------IMAGE---------------->\n  <tr>\n    <td colspan="2" align="center">\n      <img src= http://static.rappler.com/images/640-lamesadam-20120728.jpg, width=500, height = 223, alt="picture" />\n    </td>\n  </tr>\n<!------------PRIKEY---------------->\n  <tr>\n    <td bgcolor = \'#090259\', align="center" >\n      <p><font color = \'FFFFFF\', size =\'4\'>PRIKEY</p>\n    </td>\n \n    <td bgcolor = \'#d8d8ff\' align="center">\n      <p>0100026491</p>\n    </td>\n<!------------YEAR INSTALLED---------------->\n  <tr>\n    <td bgcolor = \'#090259\', align="center" >\n      <p><font color = \'FFFFFF\', size =\'4\'>Year Installed</p>\n    </td>\n \n    <td bgcolor = \'#d8d8ff\' align="center">\n      <p>2001</p>\n    </td>\n<!------------PIPE CLASS---------------->\n  <tr>\n    <td bgcolor = \'#090259\', align="center" >\n      <p><font color = \'FFFFFF\', size =\'4\'>Pipe Class</p>\n    </td>\n \n    <td bgcolor = \'#d8d8ff\' align="center">\n      <p>PRIMARY</p>\n    </td>\n<!------------DIAMETER---------------->\n  <tr>\n    <td bgcolor = \'#090259\', align="center" >\n      <p><font color = \'FFFFFF\', size =\'4\'>Diameter (mm)</p>\n    </td>\n \n    <td bgcolor = \'#d8d8ff\' align="center">\n      <p>1500.000000</p>\n    </td>\n<!------------MATERIAL---------------->\n  <tr>\n    <td bgcolor = \'#090259\', align="center" >\n      <p><font color = \'FFFFFF\', size =\'4\'>Material</p>\n    </td>\n \n    <td bgcolor = \'#d8d8ff\' align="center">\n      <p>SP</p>\n    </td>\n<!------------STATUS---------------->\n  <tr>\n    <td bgcolor = \'#090259\', align="center" >\n      <p><font color = \'FFFFFF\', size =\'4\'>Status</p>\n    </td>\n \n    <td bgcolor = \'#d8d8ff\' align="center">\n      <p>ACTIVE</p>\n    </td>\n<!------------BUSINESS ADDRESS---------------->\n  <tr>\n    <td bgcolor = \'#090259\', align="center" >\n      <p><font color = \'FFFFFF\', size =\'4\'>Business Address</p>\n    </td>\n \n    <td bgcolor = \'#d8d8ff\' align="center">\n      <p>Fairview-Commonwealth</p>\n    </td>]]>"""

# PARSE XSL FROM STRING
xslstr = '''<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs">
<xsl:output version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="description">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">&lt;![CDATA[</xsl:text>
      <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">{}</xsl:text>
      <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">]]&gt;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:copy>  
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>'''.format(newhtml)

xslt = ET.fromstring(xslstr)

# TRANSFORM SOURCE TO NEW TREE
transform = ET.XSLT(xslt)
newdom = transform(dom)

# OUTPUT TO FILE
tree_out = ET.tostring(newdom, encoding='UTF-8', pretty_print=True, xml_declaration=True)

xmlfile = open('newTrim.kml','wb')
xmlfile.write(tree_out)
xmlfile.close()
```

Comment: Hi @Parfait ! I get an error: "XMLSyntaxError: Namespace prefix xsi for schemaLocation on Document is not defined, line 3, column 32" when I use your code. I've tried studying XSLT and XML structure but I still can't make it work. Can I get more help, please? Thank you so much!

Comment: That is not an XSLT error but an XML error which comes when parsing source file: `dom = ET.parse('trim.kml')`. See my above comment. Your KML is not a well-formed XML file as it should [be](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kml_tut). The `xsi` namespace prefix needs to be declared prior to its use in `<document>` tag.